# Mistake with removing class "sticky" from "nav" after execution of pretty photo library

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

having problem with one of the scripts below, which stops working right after the pretty photo script is executed.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){  
        $(window).scroll(function(){  
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 90) {  
                $("nav").addClass("sticky");
                $(".menu_logo").css("display", "block");
                $(".menu_logo").html('<a href="/" title="Home"><img src="/images/_logo_sm.png" alt="" width="108" height="25" /></a>');
                $("#menu-bar").css("display", "block");
                $("#menu-bar").html('<div id="menu-bar-icon" ></div>');
                $("#menu-bar-icon").click(function() { 
                    $('#menu').toggle();return false;
                });
                $("#menu").css("display", "none");
                $('#search_in_bar').html($('#search').html());
            } else {  
                $("nav").removeClass("sticky");
                $(".menu_logo").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu").css("display", "block");
                $('#search_in_bar').empty().html();
                $("#menu-bar").css("display", "none");
            }  
        });  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Need more info. Jfiddle would be nice too.

Comment: @bobthyasian I have posted fiddle, cannot figure out what I have or have not done correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your code. There were a few things that needed modification but I won't name them all.

1. The `<img>` tag for the screen shot wasn't closed: `<a href="..." rel="..."><img src"..." /></a>`
2. The 'hook' was being used improperly: `rel="prettyPhoto[]"` is used for multiple images. `rel="prettyPhoto"` is for just one image.
3. Some of the CSS is redundant. Classes and IDs not being used (I won't go into that.)
4. `$('#search_in_bar').empty().html();` Makes no sense; emptying the contents of the `<div>` then asking for it's content.
5. Not linking the prettyPhoto CSS file--which is used for the popup. [Basic Style](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/wp-content/themes/NMFE/css/prettyPhoto.css)
6. Due to a lack of permissions, `pps.js`was not being loaded but was met with a 403 (Forbidden) error.
7. And most importantly, prettyPhoto was not being initialized.

> ```
> <script>
>  $(function() {
>    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
>    $(window).scroll(function (){
>    ...
>    });
>  });
> </script>
> ```

Oh, side note:

> ```
> <a href="large_here.png" rel="prettyPhoto">
> <img src="smaller_here.png" /></a>
> ```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobthyasian/bMTdr/)

Comment: Thanks for this, part of your answer was absolutely to the point, but part was not relevant to my initial question, but I have figure it all out. The problem was that after execution of a PrettyPhoto script my sticky header script was not counting because of the conflict between 2 libraries, but I have figured it all out and partially had to use javascript instead of a Jquery

Comment: I know, I didn't want to give you complete answer. 'Cause you wouldn't have learned anything. The other stuff was just bothering me. Keeping code clean and bare-minimal is not only aesthetically pleasing but will save you time and keep you from tearing your hair out whilst debugging--looking for that one missed semicolon or missing forward-slash.